# Does sem_close deallocates memory created with sem_open?

Tags: c, static, fork, valgrind, semaphore

For a project written in C, I am creating a number of semaphore with sem_open, some are binary other are counting, I don't think it matters. The semaphores are stored in a static structure (singleton) then I fork the process multiple time, and afterwards exit all my forks. The main process returns however only after I used sem_close() followed by sem_unlink() on all my semaphores.

```
void init_semaphore(void) 
{
 ru->stop = sem_open("/stop", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
...
}

void sem_close_all(void)
{
 sem_close(ru->stop);
...
 sem_unlink("/stop");
}
```

When I run valgrind I get the following errors:

```
==744644== 39 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 10 of 13                                                                                                                   
==744644==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)                                                                                               
==744644==    by 0x49107A8: __sem_check_add_mapping (sem_routines.c:104)                                                                                                                      
==744644==    by 0x49104BB: sem_open@@GLIBC_2.34 (sem_open.c:192)                                                                                                                             
==744644==    by 0x10A34F: init_semaphore                                                                            
==744644==    by 0x10A0A9: init_all                                                                                   
==744644==    by 0x10A05E: main
```

So I don't understand how to avoid those leaks that (I think) happens in my children ?... Note: I can't use sem_destroy because of project restriction.
Am I doing something wrong ? I tried to use free() on sem_t *stop, but it didn't get rid of the leaks. Is there a solution I could use to fix this, is it a valgrind false positive ?... I tried to use my sem_close_all() function at the end of all my process, but this does not fix the valgrind leak report.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example. And no, I've never seen valgrind emitting false positives.

Comment: @Haris scanf for example if it is not configured correctly. valgrind filters output and does not display known unavoidable leaks

Comment: @Haris, `valgrind` may not emit false positives, but it does sometimes report on *bona fide* leaks in glibc or other third-party libraries, about which nothing much can easily be done.  Generally speaking, these are known issues and judged to be non-problematic.  Valgrind has a mechanism for configuring patterns for suppressing certain leaks from its reports, and it is usually packaged with a fairly long list of such suppressions for glibc and common third-party libraries.

Comment: @John Bollinger Interesting, I was unaware of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry too much about it. Valgrind suppresses many other known memory leaks.

> The error-checking tools detect numerous problems in the system
> libraries, such as the C library, which come preinstalled with your
> OS. You can't easily fix these, but you don't want to see these errors
> (and yes, there are many!) So Valgrind reads a list of errors to
> suppress at startup. A default suppression file is created by the
> ./configure script when the system is built.

You can manually add it permanently yourself

> tried to use free() on sem_t *stop

Do not do this.

Comment: Also worth noting: Valgrind is reporting that the allocated block is still reachable at exit.  This is not a leak, except in the most liberal sense.

Comment: @JohnBollinger semaphores in Linux are usually created in the file system and the pointer returned is the content of this file mapped into a process address space. Basically, the process is complex enough and he can't do anything to prevent the leak. He can only silence the valgrind

Comment: Did I say something different?  I did not.  What I said is that the particular Valgrind report presented the question doesn't even describe a leak in the first place.  But yes, lest it be unclear: the OP cannot do anything in their own code to avoid the situation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger misunderstood your comment

Comment: On Linux there are 3 default leak suppressions. On FreeBSD there are 2. Not really what I'd call 'many'.